# SQL Command query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=Invalid object name 'Drivers.DriversDetailTable'.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

Keep getting the above error everytime i try and copy stuff from one database table to another, heres my code.

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection($@"Data Source = Computer\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = Drivers;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            connect.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($@"SELECT * INTO BackUpDatabase.DriversDetailTable FROM Drivers.DriversDetailTable", connect);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();
```

Comment: And what is the error?  Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: How do i tag with the database? Sorry i'm new to this, just started it today

Comment: Seems like you should use the sql-server tag.

Comment: try this: "SELECT * INTO BackUpDatabase.dbo.DriversDetailTable FROM Drivers.dbo.DriversDetailTable". Put dbo between database and table name. Or the schema your using.

Comment: You could also use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` which seems to be more common in other databases.  And you should specify column names if possible.

Comment: You could try `... FROM Drivers.dbo.DriversDetailTable` (if you don't have a custom schema)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your `database` name is `Drivers` not `schema` name

```sql
SELECT * 
INTO BackUpDatabase.DriversDetailTable 
FROM Drivers.DriversDetailTable --here schema name is missing
```

When you use two part identifer then it will be parsed as

> schemaname.tablename

So `Drivers` and `BackUpDatabase` is considered as schema names instead of database.

It should be

```sql
SELECT * 
INTO BackUpDatabase.dbo.DriversDetailTable 
FROM Drivers.schemaname.DriversDetailTable --here replace schemaname with dbo or whatever schema name
```

**Note :** When you use `INTO` clause it creates a new table. When you run second time you may get a error stating table already exist. Better to create table in prior in backup database use `INSERT INTO..select` to copy the rows

```
Insert into BackUpDatabase.dbo.DriversDetailTable (col1,col2,..)
select col1,col2,..FROM Drivers.schemaname.DriversDetailTable
```

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=The specified schema name "BackUpDatabase" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: do i have to delete the database table if it already exists because i'm getting this error

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=There is already an object named 'DriversDetailTable' in the database.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: @JohnDoe - Read my note at the end

Comment: Not really sure how to identify the database schema

Comment: @JohnDoe - check the update. To copy records use `Insert into table..select..from`

Comment: Yes, you have to delete the table if it already exists if you use `SELECT * INTO` because that is creating the table. If you dont want to create it use the more common `INSERT INTO ...`

Comment: You can also use two periods shorthand: DatabaseName..TableName

Comment: @StanShaw - I hate that shorthand.. that is where people get confused and make mistakes better to mention the schema name when you are using 3 part identifier

Comment: @Prdp Thanks for the input - When would it cause confusion unless you have identically named tables within the same database but different schemas (which I would think is a confusing/bad design - and I've never seen it)?